# Missing "Simple API Access"

Tags: google-api

I have two google accounts, in my older test one I set up "Simple API Access" like so:

[image]

On my newer account, it isn't an option:

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas to reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is only available after you turn on a service such as GCM.